# How to make a linear layout which contains other layouts in line

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

The outcome of my full code in note3
[image]

The code of the .xml code i use at my adapter.

```
        <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/Kgri"
    android:weightSum="4">  
             <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

          <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView5"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="5"
          android:textColor="@color/turkuaz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="12sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="@color/turkuaz"
        android:text="1" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/turkuaz"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="@color/turkuaz"
        android:text="1" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@color/turkuaz"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is as you can see in picture the numbers and stuff are not in line. I want to fix it  the code i gave is what i'm using for my adapters. If possible i want to make them stay in line without using dp if not its also ok.

And if i need to short what i need i want the writings to be in line like the gold bar images are.

[image]

what i want is the "fiyati" parts of all the lines to be on a line down the screen .

Comment: Have you tried left aligning the `TextView`? Try the `layout_gravity` property.

Comment: na i want it to be in middle of the textView . What i need is making the layouts anchor if possible.If i make it to left some of them will be at too right from what i guess but i'll try just to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **singleLine** attribute on `TextView`

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

If you want to align elements like in a table, use these containers: (with TextView inside TableRows)

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: added a 2nd photo to show what i need. Don't think what you say will help this.

Comment: So maybe you just want to use the gravity attribute with `android:gravity="right"` ?    Or if want you want to achieve is some sort of a table, just use the TableLayout and TableRow

Comment: i figured out the problem thanks for trying to help it seems the problem was because i used wrap_content at the textView whict the layout is next to for the changes of length in the text at left textView the right textView moves itself whict results in what u see at picture . So if i give them a "number dp" they become stable and its done. And i didn't try your table solution because this dp statement works just fine in 3 different resolution devices.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the problem thanks for trying to help it seems the problem was because i used wrap_content at the textView whict the layout is next to for the changes of length in the text at left textView the right textView moves itself whict results in what u see at picture . So if i give them a "number dp" they become stable and its done.